# How to generate lists of positive floats with a specified size, sum, and a minimum value using Hypothesis

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

This question is about the [`Hypothesis`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for property-based testing.

I want a strategy that would give me lists of positive floats with a fixed size, a specified sum, and such that no elements would be lower than some specified minimum threshold.

For example:

```
size = 5
sum_ = 1
threshold = 0.1
...
for _ in range(3)
    print(magic_strategy.example())
```

could give something like this:

```
[0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]
[0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15]
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
```

How do I write such a strategy?

---

Failed attempt with [filtering](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#filtering):

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st

size = 5
sum_ = 1
threshold = 0.1

domain_values = st.floats(min_value=0, allow_infinity=False, exclude_min=True)
domain_values_lists = st.lists(domain_values, min_size=size, max_size=size)
normalized_lists = domain_values_lists.map(lambda values: [value * sum_ / sum(values) 
                                                           for value in values])
lists_with_threshold = normalized_lists.filter(lambda values: all(value > threshold for value in values))
```

The problem with this approach is that for some reason whenever I'm taking `example` from this strategy it always gives me lists of the same value regardless of the given input parameters:

```
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, ..., 0.2]
[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, ..., 0.01]
[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, ..., 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to build some values and then map them to interval `[0, 1]`, after that -- to `[0, sum_]` with making it a partition of `sum_` (i.e. sum of elements will be equal to `sum_`) and finally -- move lower bound to `[min_value, sum_]` preserving partition property:

```py
from math import floor
from numbers import Real
from typing import List

from hypothesis import strategies
from hypothesis.strategies import SearchStrategy as Strategy

MIN_PARTITION_SIZE = 1


def to_partitions(sum_: Real,
                  *,
                  min_value: Real = 0,
                  size: int = MIN_PARTITION_SIZE,
                  base: Strategy[Real] = strategies.integers()
                  ) -> Strategy[List[Real]]:
    if size < MIN_PARTITION_SIZE:
        raise ValueError('`size` should not be less '
                         f'than {MIN_PARTITION_SIZE}.')
    if not (0 <= min_value <= sum_):
        raise ValueError(f'`min_value` should be in [0, {sum_}] interval.')
    if min_value:
        max_size_approximation = sum_ / min_value
        if math.isfinite(max_size_approximation):
            max_size = floor(max_size_approximation)
            if max_size < size:
                raise ValueError(f'`size` should not be greater than {max_size}.')

    def to_proportions(numbers: List[Real]) -> List[Real]:
        return [2 * abs(number) / (1 + number * number) for number in numbers]

    def to_partition(proportions: List[Real]) -> List[Real]:
        factor = sum_ / sum(proportions)
        return [proportion * factor for proportion in proportions]

    def bound_minimum(partition: List[Real]) -> List[Real]:
        minimum = min(partition)
        if minimum >= min_value:
            return partition
        partition_size = len(partition)
        denominator = sum_ - partition_size * minimum
        slope = sum_ - partition_size * min_value
        intercept = sum_ * (min_value - minimum)
        return [max((part * slope + intercept) / denominator, min_value)
                for part in partition]

    def normalize(partition: List[Real]) -> List[Real]:
        partition_sum = sum(partition)
        if partition_sum < sum_:
            arg_min = min(range(len(partition)),
                          key=partition.__getitem__)
            partition[arg_min] += sum_ - partition_sum
        elif partition_sum > sum_:
            arg_max = max(range(len(partition)),
                          key=partition.__getitem__)
            partition[arg_max] -= partition_sum - sum_
        return partition

    def is_valid(partition: List[Real]) -> bool:
        return sum(partition) == sum_

    return (strategies.lists(base,
                             min_size=size,
                             max_size=size)
            .filter(any)
            .map(to_proportions)
            .map(to_partition)
            .map(bound_minimum)
            .map(normalize)
            .filter(is_valid))
```

for numbers "normalization" we are using a well-known property of real numbers

```
(x - 1) ^ 2 >= 0  | since square is non-negative
x^2 + 1 >= 2 * x  | divide both sides by positive x^2 + 1
...
1 >= 2 * x / (x^2 + 1)
```

we are also adding some tricks to handle possible issues with floating point numbers (like having an element close to but less than `min_value` after moving bound to `min_value` and having sum of partition close but not equal to `sum`).

## Test

```py
from math import floor
from numbers import Real
from typing import List

from hypothesis import (given, 
                        strategies)
from hypothesis.strategies import DataObject


@given(strategies.data(), strategies.floats(0, 100))
def test_to_partitions(data: DataObject, sum_: Real) -> None:
    min_value = data.draw(strategies.floats(0, sum_))
    size = data.draw(strategies.integers(MIN_PARTITION_SIZE,
                                         floor(min(sum_ / min_value, 100))
                                         if min_value
                                         else 100))
    strategy = to_partitions(sum_,
                             min_value=min_value,
                             size=size)

    partition = data.draw(strategy)

    assert sum(partition) == sum_
    assert len(partition) == size
    assert all(part >= min_value for part in partition)
```

seems to pass.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Any idea why all of this is necessary, though? Why does my obvious approach with `filter` fail?